# Dynamic Sqoop Query and scheduling

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive, sqoop, sqoop2

My Sqoop query is stored in a DB. I need to fetch that query and execute it.
Intern that query will archieve the oracle tables and store in the HDFS.
Can anyone please let me know how can I retrieve the row from the DB(containing sqoop query) and execute it.
I am new to Hadoop/Sqoop/Hive.

Answer (score 0):

You need programming language support or you can use shell script.